# How to return distinct values that fits conditions in 1+ row?

Tags: mysql, sql

T1 **ORDERS**

```
ID       CID      STATUS    COUNTRY
01       1        1         3
02       2        7         NULL
03       1        1         2
04       4        NULL      -1
05       6        -1        3
06       1        3         2
07       4        2         4
```

I need to find all CID (Customers ID) that have orders with STATUS = '1' AND CONTRY is specified.
From data-set above CID 1 should be returned (CID 1 have multiple orders, but I just need to return just the CID with that fits the conditions at least in one order, not all of his orders)

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE Status = '1' AND CONTRY IS NOT NULL AND COUNTRY != -1
```

But is doesn't work at all.

Comment: `But is doesn't work at all.` ... _what_ is not working?  Can you include both the current and expected output?

Comment: *I need to find all CID (Customers ID) that have orders with STATUS = '1' AND COUNTRY is specified.* In the same row? or `STATUS = '1'` and `COUNTRY != -1` may occur in 2 different rows with the same CID?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT CID
FROM ORDERS
WHERE Status = '1' AND CONTRY > 0  (please try this one)

Comment: Looks like a typo - `U` missed in `.. CONTRY IS NOT NULL ..`. From the other side, `COUNTRY != -1` makes checking for NULL excess, and it can be removed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Just take more care...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,cid INT NOT NULL
,status INT NULL
,country INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1 ,      1   ,     1      ,   3),
(2 ,      2   ,     7      ,   NULL),
(3 ,      1   ,     1      ,   2),
(4 ,      4   ,     NULL   ,   -1),
(5 ,      6   ,     -1     ,   3),
(6 ,      1   ,     3      ,   2),
(7 ,      4   ,     2      ,   4);

SELECT DISTINCT cid FROM my_table WHERE status = 1 AND country != -1;
+-----+
| cid |
+-----+
|   1 |
+-----+
```